# How many people would have to keep it a secret if the U.S. hadn't walked on the moon?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, apollo-11

For [another question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13918/can-you-really-use-arduino-for-a-small-spacecraft), @user answered: "The kind of people who dismiss the hundreds of thousands who worked directly on the Apollo project, the hundreds of thousands to millions who watched the spacecraft launches live"

But suppose the moon landing was fake, how many people would have to keep it a secret? Because we can easily assume that everyone who saw it on TV doesn't know about the fake. Likewise, not everyone at NASA would know about it (for example, the little technician who fixes coffee machines probably wouldn't know it was fake).

So how many people would have to keep it a secret?

Comment: I love Capricorn One. Liquidate those who don't comply.

Comment: agreeing with the close voters:  the question is asking you to imagine how big such a conspiracy would have to be.  There's not a good fact-based way to answer this.

Comment: 42 people, definitely. Also [That Mitchell & Webb Look - Moon Landings](https://youtu.be/5muY64Oyp10?t=275)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the minimum set would be if we had developed all the capabilities required to walk on the moon, but we had also secretly developed capabilities to fake the moon landing with special effects, and for some reason decided to fake the landings even though we had all the capabilities to perform them.  That set would included the astronauts for all the landing missions, all the scientists who examined the moon rocks, the special effects technicians, and whatever shadowy people were coordinating all these fake activities and assiduously duping the many thousands of others who would be working closely with the conspirators and would know enough about the mission to spot things not adding up. So definitely in the hundreds if not low thousands of individuals.  Because the radio signals from the moon missions were picked up by the Soviets and others who would not have been in on the conspiracy, the technology to fake the moon mission would probably have to be more advanced-- and certainly have to be far more secret-- than the technology to actually perform the mission.

If the moon landing were faked because the capabilities that were developed to perform the moon landings were also faked (which is the only non-absurd reason to fake them), then you are talking many thousands of additional people who developed and documented those capabilities who also have to be in on the conspiracy.